# JQuery selector using variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, syntax-error, selector

Been receiving this error whatever way round it i go. Any ideas?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /disks/diskh/zco/comw/html-olGEUddM/wedding/wedding_results.php on line 85
```

Heres my code:

```
if($("'#".$row['name']."'")){//error in this line
  $newHTML = "";
  $select = $("#" . $row['name'] . "Select");
  $select.options[select.options.length] = new Option($newDate,$newDate);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you gave us the right line ? And BTW, on the first selector you're using ', and on the second you do not. Maybe that's the problem (the second is wrong)

Comment: If you are using `php` then your `php` code is not getting parsed, replace `.$row['name'].` with `<?php echo $row['name']; ?>` and try

Comment: It doesnt even reach the second selector. It just throws the error and stops.

Comment: Oh blimey, you can tell ive been sat here cracking away at this. Im attempting to use a JQuery selector for a HTML element that isnt even in the page yet. Apologies ill close this

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your javascript with php. You need to be passing the if as a string:

```
echo "if($('#".$row['name']."')){";
```

That or if you want that if statement to be in php. You cannot try to evaluate javascript in it. Javascript is evaluated at the browser. Not the server.